# Change layout var date email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates, date, email-translation

Inside a transactional email whe print a date attribute, using the following code:
 `{{var quote.followup}}`

This only displays the date as 2017-12-11 00:00:00

How can I change that into Mondag 11 December 2017?

Comment: Magento version ?

Comment: @KeyurShah Magento 1.9

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code below:

`{{var quote.followup|formatDateTime:d/m/Y H:i}}`

May be it will help!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried that line, but it still displays as 2017-12-11 00:00:00.